# Laravel 5 Model class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created model class in `app` root directory. Since laravel 5 use `app` root directory for models. I didn't created another folder for `Models`.

```
class Posts extends Eloquent{}
```

And in `routes.php` :

```
Route::get('/', function () {

  $painting = Posts;
  $painting->title = 'Do no Wrong';
  $painting->artist = 'D. Do right';
  $painting->year = 2014;
  $painting->save();

  return view('welcome');
});
```

It throws the following error :

```
Class 'Painting' not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filename of your Model must reflect the class name. So for a `Posts` model, the file should be named `Posts.php`. Assuming the model has been placed in the `App/` directory of your Laravel installation, the Model should look something like this:

```
<?php 

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Posts extends Model 
{

}
```

You can then access the `Posts` model in your route under the `App` namespace as `App\Posts`:

```
Route::get('/', function () {

  $painting = new App\Posts;
  $painting->title = 'Do no Wrong';
  $painting->artist = 'D. Do right';
  $painting->year = 2014;
  $painting->save();

  return view('welcome');
});
```

The above should work, but I would recommend using non-plural names for your Models. So ideally your `Posts` Model should be called `Post`, while the table in the database will be called `posts`. This is the [convention Laravel expects you to follow](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage) when naming your classes and database tables.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$painting = Posts;` to `$painting = new Posts;`

Additionally, I think you're supposed to create Eloquent models like so:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Posts extends Model
```

Instead of trying to extend 'Eloquent'.

Comment: Sorry for the silly mistake .
Now the error is `Class 'Painting' not found`

Comment: Did you change it to `$painting = new Painting;` by mistake? Your model class is named Posts in your example.

Comment: Yeah soory its Posts ! 
Still the same error 
`Class Posts not found`.

Comment: Does changing it to `$painting = new App\Posts;` still cause the error?

Comment: @Shafee is your models filename `Posts.php`? The filename must reflect the classname.

Answer (score 0):

you can save records use create method

```
Posts::create([ 'title' => 'Do no Wrong', 'artist' = 'D. Do right']);
```

or simply you can instance Posts class and use your code.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  $painting = new Posts;
  $painting->title = 'Do no Wrong';
  $painting->artist = 'D. Do right';
  $painting->year = 2014;
  $painting->save();
  return view('welcome');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the namespace and new statement;

Try:

```
Route::get('/', function () {

  $painting = new App\Posts;
  $painting->title = 'Do no Wrong';
  $painting->artist = 'D. Do right';
  $painting->year = 2014;
  $painting->save();

  return view('welcome');
});
```

Your model should look like this:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Posts extends Model{

}
```

Comment: `class App\Posts not found` :(

Comment: That means your model namespace is not correct. check my updated answer

Comment: @Shafee Your file name should be `posts.php` also run `composer dump-autoload` if issue persist